# iPhone Undocumented API of Security.framework

Tags: iphone, security, reverse-engineering, iphone-privateapi

I read some info regarding getting .h files for undocumented API. Most of sources recommend class-dump (or class-dump-x and class-dump-z).

However it doesn't work with iPhone Security.framework. It doesn't contain Objective-C runtime information.

The only other way which I found is to use `nm` or `otool`. This will give the names of functions and disassembly for them.

Does anybody know some faster way to get undocumented functions signature than reading disassembly and trying to figure out what parameters go where and what could it be?

Comment: Why do you want to use undocumented API's? Apple will reject any application that uses undocumented API's.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski.  Maybe he wants to get a phone call from Steve Jobs. http://www.businessinsider.com/steve-jobs-personally-calls-a-developer-after-his-app-is-rejected-2010-11

Comment: @YWE: I think Steve Jobs met his personal phone call quota for the decade with that one.

Comment: So you are wanting documentation for undocumented API? ...:-/

Comment: a) You can use undocumented API's to write application for jailbroken phone (you don't need Apple approval for that).

Comment: b) You can write enterprise applications using undocumented API. I have no idea where it stands from legal point, but again Apple have nothing to do with iPhone enterprise apps.

Comment: You signed an agreement that you wouldn't use private APIs. I think that applies to all apps, not just ones you submit to the App Store. Whether Apple can tell or care enough to enforce it is another issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean this undocumented api, [documented here..](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Security.framework is not private or undocumented.

As far as headers go, installed on my harddrive in the 3.2 sdk i find:

/Security.framework/Headers/Security.h
/Security.framework/Headers/Secbase.h
/Security.framework/Headers/SecCertificate.h
/Security.framework/Headers/SecIdentitiy.h
/Security.framework/Headers/SecImportExport.h
/Security.framework/Headers/SecItem.h
/Security.framework/Headers/SecKey.h
/Security.framework/Headers/SecPolicy.h
/Security.framework/Headers/SecRandom.h
/Security.framework/Headers/SecTrust.h

As for a little reverse engineering 101, you should realise that a framework doesn't contain or in anyway have a use for header files, or function signatures. When provided they are solely for the benefit of the developer. There is no C or C++ or objective-c code in the compiled framework, only the raw machine code.

As you have seen, if objective-c was used Class-Dump can do a pretty good job of arranging objective-c symbols into something that looks like a header file, only missing type information that isn't used at runtime, so still not that useful.

If the source language was C then you are screwed. There may be a function name symbol but there is no info about arguments or return type.

Comment: Actually, C++ function names contain complete argument type information (and possibly return type information); they have to for overloading to work.

Answer (score 1):

There are bunch of additional undocumented API's which are not mentioned in official documentation. As example, part of them could be seen here:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55163.44/sec/Security/